# How to make a VBA variable accessible and modifiable by all subs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA code the open a program called Putty that's useful to acess remove Unix servers.

But I think my problem is a VBA issue, all the alternatives that I've seen to automation a putty seccion with VBA stores the user's password in an ecplicit cell, and I wanna hide this infomration to avoid future problems.

The solution I've found was to open a inputbox to require a user's password every time the workbook is opend. So, the password is stored into a variable until the workbook gets closed and the user needs to type his password just once for all the Putty sessions.

But I'm facing a scope problem, because the sub to open the Putty after double click cannot acess the value of the password set after the workbook gets opend.

```
Public password As String 'I tried to make the password variable acessful for all subs

Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    senha = InputBox("Type your password:")
    MsgBox password
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Shell "putty.exe "username"@" & ActiveCell, 1
    MsgBox password ' this code return a empity msgbox
    cancel = True
End Sub
```

Could some one help me with this?

Comment: hi. u are using the variable password has public and using the variable senha... u must use allways the same...

Comment: Like @LuisCurado mentioned, you need to say `password = InputBox("Type your password:")` and `MsgBox password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module:

```
Option Explicit
Public password As String 'I tried to make the password variable acessful for all subs

Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    senha = InputBox("Type your password:")
    MsgBox senha
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Shell "putty.exe "username"@" & ActiveCell, 1
    MsgBox senha ' this code return a empity msgbox
    cancel = True
End Sub
```

This will enable compile-time validation and force you to declare all your variables - the above code will not compile, because `senha` isn't declared anywhere. Use the `Dim` statement to declare locals:

```
Option Explicit
Public password As String 'I tried to make the password variable acessful for all subs

Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim senha As String
    senha = InputBox("Type your password:")
    MsgBox senha
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Shell "putty.exe "username"@" & ActiveCell, 1
    MsgBox senha ' <~ still won't compile. can you see why?
    cancel = True
End Sub
```

Here `MsgBox senha` will not compile in the `BeforeDoubleClick` handler, because the variable is *out of scope*: it lives and dies in the scope of the `Open` handler.

So what you need to do, is assign the `password` when you prompt for it:

```
Option Explicit
Public password As String

Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    password = InputBox("Type your password:")
    MsgBox password
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Shell "putty.exe "username"@" & ActiveCell.Value, 1
    MsgBox password
    cancel = True
End Sub
```

Note that there's no need to declare a `senha` local variable anymore... but that still won't work. Why? Because `password` is `Public`, yes - but it's an *instance variable* that belongs to the `ThisWorkbook` object: it's not *global*. If you want to access it, you need to do it through the `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Shell "putty.exe "username"@" & ActiveCell.Value, 1
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.password
    cancel = True
End Sub
```

And that will work as expected.

If you want a real global variable, you need to declare it in a *standard module* (not a class module, not a workbook or worksheet module, and not a form module):

```
Option Explicit
Public password As String
```

If this is `Module1`, then other code everywhere in your project can access it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Module1.password = InputBox("Type your password:")
    MsgBox Module1.password
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Shell "putty.exe "username"@" & ActiveCell.Value, 1
    MsgBox Module1.password
    cancel = True
End Sub
```

Note that the `Module1` qualifier is optional, ...but recommended. Also note that global variables aren't ideal, since they can be written to by anything anywhere: best practice would be to limit the scope and visibility of variables to the bare minimum, and prefer passing parameters instead (of course, event handlers' signatures can't be modified to do this, so module-scope variables and globals are pretty much the only way for event handlers to access data that was assigned elsewhere).

Comment: Is it correct to read it as it is an instance variable, in this case, precisely because it is in ThisWorkbook and ThisWorkbook is different from standard modules in some particular way? I have seen you reference it as a type of module before (I hope I haven't misquoted you).

Comment: @QHarr correct. `ThisWorkbook` (and worksheet modules) is a *document module* (owned by the host application); they're a special kind of class modules, to make a long story short ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry but I made a mistake when I transleted the code, the variable senha and passwd were suppost to be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your method woked for me. I added the "Option Explicit" and separated the subs into two differents files on Microsoft Excel Objects folder. Then I refer the varible names on plan1 as thisworkbbok.password.

Comment: @MauroMatsudo feel free to mark the question as "answered", by clicking the hollow green checkmark near the top of the post.